# Selenium Google Translate Website doesn't detect elements

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, proxy

I'm trying to use Google translate as a proxy for the website I'm scraping. But I can't detect elements from the website. [This is the link](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=tr&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sahibinden.com%2Fsatilik). I pass the website through Google Translate and it acts as a proxy. But when I use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")`it only detects Google Translate's elements. How can I detect elements from the actual website? Or is there any alternatives for that? This website only accepts Turkish IP addresses but I can't find enough free ones.

Answer (score 2):

Try switching to Iframe before trying to get contents of your website.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id,'contentframe']/iframe"));
```